# Can we run flash file from java through pure java code?

Tags: java

How can I run a flash file from in pure Java (i.e., not relying on a DLL etc.) from within a runnable jar file?

The only solution I could find uses `JFlashPlayer`, which is platform dependent as it requires some dlls to run the flash file.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already found, there is no pure Java ability to do that. Flash is played by adobe flash player and it is written with platform dependent code. If it is appropriate, I would advise you to negotiate the requirements with your customer.

Answer (score 0):

What about open a browser with the right parameter ( URL ) and give it the swf ? You can embarq the SWF in the JAR file if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the JFlashPlayer from DJ Native Swing: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns

It relies on the SWT Browser which integrates a native runtime and in which the Flash plugin gets loaded. It also eases integration of SWT in Swing so that it almost looks like a standard Swing component